# HTTP state 500 in JSP and use JSONObject

Tags: jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea, jar, artifacts

i'm using Intellij IDEA 14 ULTIMATE to create a web application.
I wanna use html to show and jsp to connect data between java and html display.
So I use JSONObject, after import json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
use methods of request/response, after import javax.servlet.jsp-api (from maven)
and tomcat jar generate by project auto.
[image: dependencs]

any one i delete, there would be a compile error.
i run tomcat, browser show:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/servlet/getArticle_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class objects for the type he.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager; used in the signature

type Exception report

message java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/servlet/getArticle_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class objects for the type he.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager; used in the signature

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/servlet/getArticle_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class objects for the type he.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager; used in the signature
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:348)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/servlet/getArticle_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class objects for the type he.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager; used in the signature
    org.apache.jsp.servlet.getArticle_jsp._jspInit(getArticle_jsp.java:34)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:180)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:376)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.64 logs.
```

Tomcat Localhost Log:

```
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
严重: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/servlet/getArticle_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class objects for the type he.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager; used in the signature] with root cause
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/servlet/getArticle_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class objects for the type he.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager; used in the signature
    at org.apache.jsp.servlet.getArticle_jsp._jspInit(getArticle_jsp.java:34)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:180)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:376)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

#### EDIT:

**I'm so confused about jar import, module, Library, lib package, lib package in out and Artifacts.**

Comment: Looks like you have incompatible jars in your classpath

Comment: @Jens incompatible? I thought it would cause by jars conflict?<br/>anyway, so what jar should i import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem mostly caused by jar conflict, you should:

- dont import servlet-api and jsp-api from maven, there is so many jar pack and it would not be completely consistency with your own tomcat api.
- import these two jar (just them, thats enough) from your local file folder , the tomcat home folder in your project `Moudles`->`Dependencies`
- import json jar pack, there have three I recommend：
      
  ①json-lib（net.sf.json）   
  ②org.json   
  ③json-simple
  2 & 3 is lightweight, can be used directly by import it to  `Moudles`->`Dependencies` **AND** copy them in your `web->WEB-INF->lib`
  if you choose the first one, you must import `commons-beanutils`
  `commons-collections` `commons-lang` `commons-logging` `ezmorph` further.
  use them in a same version pack better:)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have some of this jars on your generated war:
`Servlet-api.jar` or `javax-servlet-api.jar` or `jsp-api.jar` or `javax-servlet-jsp.jar`

Run

```
mvn clean package
```

Test again

Comment: What is 'war'?What is 'Artifacts'? where is mvn?

Comment: are you using maven?

Comment: part of, more import from file